# Android, SAX and Cookies: How to add a cookie when trying to parse XML from an URL

Tags: android, xml, parsing, cookies, sax

I want to parse the result of a specific URL using Simple Ajax for XML. This is basically my Code:

```
URL link = new URL(url); // url is just a string representing the url
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
xr.setContentHandler(myHandler);  // the class of myHandler extends from DefaultHandler
InputStream stream = link.openStream();
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(stream);
inputSource.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
 xr.parse(inputSource);
```

But how can I add a cookie? I know I can add Cookies to HttpClients like so:

```
BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie("access_token", accessToken);
mHttpClient.getCookieStore().addCookie(cookie);
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("www.reeple.net/xml/login/" + uid);
mHttpClient.execute(request);
```

But how can I add a cookie to a request, that is handlet by the SAX-Api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step #1: Use `HttpClient` to retrieve the XML as a string, using whatever cookies you want

Step #2: Use SAX to parse the string retrieved by `HttpClient`

Comment: I dont see any method of HttpClient that returns a string

Comment: @paskter: Check the first bullet here: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html  Or, check here: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Service/WeatherAPI